# How writing 'A' in Ruby in commandline

Tags: ruby

I need writing character
How writing script to showing char 'A' in console.

```
puts 'A' without  new line
```

or other way

Comment: I'm guessing you want the return to not display `nil`.  Use `return 'A'`

Comment: @philipyoo With `return 'A'` I get a `unexpected return (LocalJumpError)`.

Comment: @knut The `return` statement works only within a block or method. If you wanted to print and also return 'A', then try `p 'A'`. Also, just using `'A'` will return itself but not print to console

Answer (score 1):

This is simple

```
print "A\n" with new line
print "A" without
```

runing 
$ruby filename.rb

$ruby -e "print 'A'"

$ruby -e "print 65.chr"

```
$irb
>print 'A'.encode('utf-8')
```

$stdout.print "A"

Comment: `print` won't add a `"\n"` new-line character, but `puts` will. It's kind of odd to use `print` with a newline when `puts` is shorter and already does that.